# JVisualVM: "Local Applications Cannot Be Detected"

Tags: java, temp, jvisualvm

I would like to monitor a local Java application using JVisualVM. When I'm starting it, the popup 'Local java application cannot be monitored' or 'Local Applications Cannot Be Detected' is shown. I have read [here](http://visualvm.java.net/troubleshooting.html#jpswin) that it is a permissions problem. Every time when I grant full access to folder `%TMP%hsperfdata_MY_USER_ID` to me (logged user) and everyone (windows user), the permissions are reset when I start JVisualVM.

I know that another solution is to delete hsperfdata_MY_USER_ID, but why  does the permissions trick not work? Is the permissions folder reset a Windows feature?

System : Windows 7

Tested on cmd started as administrator. I use the same accounts and I do not pass any JVM parameters such as com.sun.management.jmxremote.port=XXXX.

Comment: which parameters do you pass to the JVM in order to enable monitoring by visualvm ? Are VisualVM and the application both run under the same account ?

Comment: Hi Marged, I use same account and I do not pass any parameter. Do you mean one of these _com.sun.management.jmxremote.port=XXXX_?

Comment: I moved your comment to the question body. How is the application being run? Is it being run as a service, or are you running it manually?

Comment: @PawełDulęba yes, I am talking about these. Try to specify them and do not run the program as a service (if you did before)

Comment: Original 'here' link is dead, updated link: https://visualvm.github.io/troubleshooting.html#jpswin

Answer (score 5):

For people stumbling here who have a FAT-type file system:

- Make a directory (e.g. `e:\temp`) on an NTFS disk.
- Start both `java` and `jvisualvm` with an environment variable `TMP=E:\temp`.

There are three options to set the environment variable for java:

- In your IDE, go to the project options or launch options and find the 'Environment' entry, then enter `TMP=E:\temp`
- Open a `cmd` prompt, and execute `set TMP=E:\temp` before launching youur java application from the same prompt.
- Put the two lines you'd enter at the cmd prompt in a `.bat` file. Optinally add `pause` at the end of the bat file to prevent the console window from disappearing in case of a runtime exception or vm crash.

Similarly, for JVisualVM, use one of the last two options.

Comment: I don't recommend setting the TMP environment variable system-wide.

Answer (score 2):

I had the 'Local Applications Cannot Be Monitored' problem, got it solved like this:

1. Exit all java processes
2. Delete existing folder %TMP%\hsperfdata_username
3. Start jvisualvm, which created the folder with a different casing: %TMP%\hsperfdata_USERNAME

My problem and solution have nothing to do with permissions, so may not work for the original problem in the question.

Also see https://visualvm.github.io/troubleshooting.html#jpswin

Answer (score 1):

My username: **A4000000**

I had to delete `C:\Users\A4000000\AppData\Local\Temp\hsperfdata_a4000000`

AppData is a hidden folder.

Then once starting VisualVM again, it created the following:

```
 C:\Users\A4000000\AppData\Local\Temp\hsperfdata_A4000000
```

Notice the **case** difference.

Then start:

```
C:\visualvm_213\bin>  visualvm.exe --jdkhome "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_202" --userdir "C:\Temp\visualvm_userdir"
```

Comment: I delete with temp folder, and restart JVisualVM (jdk1.8.0_291). I don't select --jdkhome and --userdir in start input params. JVisualVM started and detedted java process. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is a bit trivial but might still save time.

Check your java application is not lauched with the "-XX:-UsePerfData" option.